# Move and change color of an object

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I want do move an object and change its color, so as if it looks like it appears.

```
<animate 
           xlink:href="#object"
           attributeName="fill"
           values="#FFFFF;#0000FF"
           dur="3s"
           fill="freeze"/>

<animateMotion 
           xlink:href="#object"
           dur="3s"
           fill="freeze"><mpath xlink:href="#route" /> </animateMotion>
```

Comment: OK, you seem to have code to do that, what's the problem?

Comment: Ah ok, now its working. Haha sorry